# Browsing redirected and ad playing in background - Malware?

Tags: antivirus, malware

Recently i have noticed when browsing a web page will be redirected to something other than what i click on. For instance, when i tried going to www.askubuntu.com via a link on ubuntu.com it redirected me to some other site than this one.

Also when on a page with no flash videos of any kind or pop up windows an ad will start playing. The only way to get it to stop is to wait for it to finish or close the browser and start over again. I have run Clam AV but it has not found anything.

Comment: Could it be that something has been changed to your DNS, or someone has been fscking around in your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: I am a newbie to ubuntu. I know what a host file but not sure where to find it in Linux to check. I am the only user of this laptop and i know i haven't.

Comment: Well, you could type something like `less /etc/hosts` in a console, and see if something funky is going on there. You might for good measure do the same with `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @Tim - is this while you are on Ubuntu or are you also running Windows on the machine?

Comment: the host file looks normal. It has the standard 1270.0.1 in there but nothing else. The other one shows nothing out of the ordinary either.

Comment: @cprofitt in ubuntu not in a windows. Windows is not running on this machine.

Comment: Odd -- I have heard of malware that does that in Windows, but not OS X or Linux. The music / ads playing in the background makes this interesting. I was hoping you were running Windows in a VM or Ubuntu in a VM because then the issue might have been easier to fix.

Comment: my thoughts exactly.

Comment: @Tim -- you might want to run a rootkit detector. http://www.rootkit.nl/projects/rootkit_hunter.html

Comment: I tried looking up how to install from a tar.gz but  it is not working. i typed in "tar zxvf rkhunter-1.4.0.tar.gz" but i keep getting errors and it won't do it. do i have to be a root user?

Comment: @Tim sudo apt-get install rkhunter

Comment: @Tim -- if you can post this on http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=338 or if you have irc you can pint me on IRC and I can try to walk you through some things.

Comment: I have posted this issue on the ubuntu forums as well. I will see about the IRC thing.

Answer (score 0):

All answers to this question will be speculative. In that vein, I suggest experimenting with another browser. Which browser are you using? Firefox? Try Chrome. `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`. Chrome? Try Firefox `sudo apt-get install firefox`. My guess would be some misbehaving browser extension. If so, a completely different browser would help demonstrate.

Comment: Even this answer is speculative. To be honest this question might be much better on ubuntuforums.org - because it will likely take multiple steps to determine what the 'cause' is and then more to solve the issue.

Comment: its doing the redirecting in both browsers and only the sound ad thing in firefox.